# Batching Neo4J updates for speed

Tags: neo4j, neo4jclient

My goal is to have a list of words in the Oxford dictionary with a relationship between them called IS_ONE_STEP_AWAY_FROM. Each word in relationship is the same length and varies by only one letter.

I am currently able to batch insert the words themselves, but how can I batch insert these relationships?

```
    class Word
    {
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }

    public void SeedDatabase()
    {
        var words = new Queue<Word>();
        EnqueueWords(words);

        //Create the words as a batch
        GraphClient.Cypher
            .Create("(w:Word {words})")
            .WithParam("words", words)
            .ExecuteWithoutResults();

        //Add relationships one word at a time
        while (words.Count > 0)
        {
            var word = words.Dequeue();
            var relatedWords = WordGroups[word.Value].Except(Enumerable.Repeat(word.Value, 1)).ToList();
            if (relatedWords.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (string relatedWord in relatedWords)
                {
                    GraphClient.Cypher
                        .Match("(w1 :Word { Value : {rootWord} }), (w2 :Word { Value : {relatedWord} })")
                        .Create("(w1)-[r:IS_ONE_STEP_AWAY_FROM]->(w2)")
                        .WithParam("rootWord", word.Value)
                        .WithParam("relatedWord", relatedWord)
                        .ExecuteWithoutResults();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Peter do you have an index or constraint on `:Word(Value)` ?

I also don't fully understand how this batches:

```
    GraphClient.Cypher
        .Create("(w:Word {words})")
        .WithParam("words", words)
        .ExecuteWithoutResults();
```

And where you define the property-name (aka `Value`).

Do you run this currently concurrently?

For the relationships I'd recommend to group them by start-word.

then you could do something like:

```
MATCH (w1:Word {Value:{rootWord}})
UNWIND {relatedWords} as relatedWord
MATCH (w2:Word {Value:relatedWord}}
CREATE (w1)-[r:IS_ONE_STEP_AWAY_FROM]->(w2);
```

Neo4jClient also still have to learn to use the new transactional endpoint.

Comment: The local variable named words is a Queue<Word>. The Word class has a property named Value. Neo4JClient allows you not only to specify a single word to create, but if you pass an IEnumerable as the parameter value it will execute as a batch. So, in the above code example the Queue<Word> (words) has 75,000 words in it so they all get created in a single instruction.

I now want to know how to do the same with relationships rather than having a 2 level loop.

Comment: And I have the following constraint GraphClient.CreateIndex("Word_Value", new IndexConfiguration { Type = IndexType.exact }, IndexFor.Node);

Comment: No, the constraint has to be `CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (w:Word) asswert w.Value IS UNIQUE` what you created was a "legacy index from Neo4j 1.9"

Comment: Did my second suggestion work? For the import you might be better of just using a thin http WebRequest POST with your cypher statements to the transactional http endpoint, neo4j.com/docs/stable/rest-api-transactional.html#rest-api-begin-and-commit-a-transaction-in-one-request

Comment: I've not had a chance to try yet, but I will definitely let you know once I  have :)